# To replace NULL records with an integer

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

My Manager wants me replace all NULL values/records in the Fact Table with -1. However when I put the script below in the OLE DB Source >> SQL Command >> SQL Command Text it does not work. Previously I've tried replacing NULL records with an integer 1 but he wanted me to replace all NULL values with negative -1 instead of just 1. If I run the script below in SSMS, It works fine! it gives me the results I need and all NULL values reflected as -1. However, when I put the script in OLE DB source >> SQL Command >> SQL Command Text, it doesnt work when I use -1. But it works fine with an integer 1 only.

Look at my -1 in the case when section.

```
Select 
case when d.ResourceKey is NULL then -1 else d.ResourceKey end as ResourceKey, 
convert(int,convert(varchar(8),dateadd(dd,-datepart(dw,getdate()),getdate()),112)) as TimeKey, 
case when A.AusFunctionKey is NULL then -1 else A.AusFunctionKey end as AusFunctionKey, 
case when I.IntFunctionKey is NULL then -1 else I.IntFunctionKey end as IntFunctionKey, 
case when o.RegionViewKey is NULL then -1 else o.RegionViewKey end as RegionViewKey, 
case when E.EntityKey is NULL then -1 else E.entityKey end as EmployingEntityKey,
r.ResourceID, 
r.SubSubFunctionCode, 
r.SubLocationCode, 
r.Site, 
t.SiteDesc, 
sum(t.ItemValue1) as HoursOutstanding, 
sum(t.ItemValue1 * isnull(case when t.itemvalue2 = 0 then r.CostRateRegOper else r.CostRateIntOper end,0)) as OperCostOutstanding,
sum(t.ItemValue1 * isnull(case when t.itemvalue2 = 0 then r.ChargeRateRegOper else r.ChargeRateIntOper end,0)) as OperRevenueOutstanding,
sum(t.ItemValue1 * isnull(case when t.itemvalue2 = 0 then r.CostRateRegHome else r.CostRateIntHome end,0)) as HomeCostOutstanding,
sum(t.ItemValue1 * isnull(case when t.itemvalue2 = 0 then r.ChargeRateRegHome else r.ChargeRateIntHome end,0)) as HomeRevenueOutstanding,
r.HomeCurrCode,
sum(t.ItemValue1 * isnull(case when t.itemvalue2 = 0 then r.CostRateRegNat else r.CostRateIntNat end,0)) as NatCostOutstanding,
sum(t.ItemValue1 * isnull(case when t.itemvalue2 = 0 then r.ChargeRateRegNat else r.ChargeRateIntNat end,0)) as NatRevenueOutstanding,
r.NatCurrCode 

from
ODS_CurrentResource r 
left outer join ODS_Staff_Task t 
on R.RESOURCEID = T.RESOURCEID
left outer join DWResourceTask.dbo.DimResource D
on T.RESOURCEID = D.RESOURCEID
left outer join DWResourceTask.dbo.DimAustralianFunction A
on R.SubSubFunctionCode = A.SubSubFunctionCode
left outer join DWResourceTask.dbo.DimInternationalFunction I
on R.SubSubFunctionCode = I.SubSubFunctionCode
left outer join DWResourceTask.dbo.DimRegion o
on R.SubLocationCode = o.SubLocationCode 
left outer join DWResourceTask.dbo.DimEntity E
on R.LegalEntity = E.EntCode

where r.resourcetypecode <> 'C'
and t.sitedesc = r.resourcesite
and t.TaskTypeID in (5,6) --missing time
group by d.ResourceKey, A.AusFunctionKey, I.IntFunctionKey, o.RegionViewKey, E.EntityKey, r.ResourceID, r.SubSubFunctionCode, r.SubLocationCode, r.Site, t.SiteDesc, 
t.Resourceid,r.HomeCurrCode, r.NatCurrCode
```

Is there any better integer that I could use instead of 1 or -1? DO you have any suggestions? The one that would work in SSIS?

Many Thanks!!

Comment: One thing pops to mind. If you're going to do this all the time then change your writing code. If you're only going to do this once, why not write SQL for each table separately.

Comment: Hi Preet, this is a fact table that's why I need to create a single script to gather data from 5 diff dimensions.